# How is OnDispose of control called - c#

Tags: c#

My designer.cs file has this stub:

```
  protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
  {
     if (disposing && (components != null))
     {
        components.Dispose();
     }
     base.Dispose(disposing);
  }
```

I have a C# application that has a form that i invoke my user control on. When I close the form, do i have to explicitly call the usercontrol.Dipose method?

Answer (score 2):

When you close the form, it may not have its `Dispose` method called immediately by the garbage collector (unless it lives in a `using` block).

However, it is sufficient to invoke `Dispose` method of the form, since that will (eventually) call `Dispose` on all controls in its `Controls` collection (and each control will in turn call `Dispose` on all controls in their Controls collection and so on), so in the end the Dispose method of your `UserControl` will also get called.

Answer (score 0):

If the object is not in a using block, then yes, you have to call the dispose method.

That being said, you could incorporate the dispose method in the finalizer of the control object, so that when the object is disposed by the GC the dispose method is called.  This kind of defeats the purpose of having the Dispose method (since the dispose method is used to release child objects before the parent object goes to the GC), but you know objects explicitly closed by that method  are called.

```
bool disposed

~Object 
{
  if(!disposed)
      Dispose();
}
```

[Dispose and finalizers link](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/33167/0/page/2)

[Another dispose and finalizers link (Joe Duffy)](http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/PermaLink.aspx?guid=88e62cdf-5919-4ac7-bc33-20c06ae539ae)

Comment: Kevin, would this be a similar behavior for a C# control being invoked by a C++ app? That the C++ app would ave to explicitly call the dispose method.

Comment: hmm I can't say for certain, as I've never done it from a C++ app, but I would assume that you would still have to call it from the C++ app.

Answer (score 0):

When you close the form, if it was not opened model, then the framework will call its Dispose method.  If it was opened by a call to ShowModel then you have to call it's Dispose method seperatly.

If your UserControl has been added to the Controls collection of the form, then when the form's Dispose method runs, it will also call Dispose on your user control.